# Problems with certain git repos in GitKraken and Atom, causing Atom to be unusable

Tags: git, magento, atom-editor, gitkraken

We have recently tried switching from Sublime to Atom, and started using GitKraken also (we've mostly just been working with git in command line)

We have some projects with git in it that cause serious issues. One main was that we work in almost daily is a Magento 1.9 site (although, we have other Magento 1.9 sites on git repos that have no problem with Atom). What happens is we open the project in Atom and we cannot open any files. It seems to hang on initializing git info (folders stay uncolored).

Sometimes when we open up the project in Atom it works, most of the time it doesnt. We HAVE noticed a 1:1 correlation with GitKraken when this occurs - when we try to open the repo in gitkraken we get an error that it could not find any repo - even though it actually loads the repo just fine, albeit after a long delay. Other time this does not occur, and that's when it opens fine in Atom. We could leave it sitting there for a couple of hours untouched and come back to it and all of a sudden we cannot open any files. This happens to all users in the office.

The problem with atom is definitely related to git. If we remove the repo and open the project then it works with no issues.

I thought, maybe repo size or history had something to do with it, so we tried initializing a fresh repo, added the files and made our first commit, and still the same problem. Our git ignore file is almost identical to the other magento sites that have no problems with Atom or Gitkraken.

Honestly it's such a weird problem I don't even know who to submit the bug report to, and we haven't found anything in our searching.

**** One thing that we've discovered of note, every time we have this issue, if we run Git GUI within that git repo folder (simply just open git gui) then all of the problems with Atom and GitKraken disappear for a time. Eventually the problems just come back though.

Comment: Do those problematic git repos have submodules?

Comment: Nope, no submodules, I just did a search for any .git folders too that I may not have been aware of, nothing

Comment: What Operating system, version of atom and version of gitkraken are you using? Do you have an example repository you'd be willing to share (publicly or privately)? You could submit the issue to us at nodegit (https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit), as nodegit is used for both and may be the culprit, and it would disseminate well to both Gitkraken and Atom teams from there as well.

Comment: I'd be willing to send it privately, sure! We have found that this mostly happens when running a Git repo over the network that's on our dev server, either directly or through a mapped network drive. If we clone the repo directly to our local machine, the problems do not occur. We're all running windows 10 machines.



I stopped digging into it because we plan to just start using local virtual machines when developing moving forward and just cloning to our individual computers, rather than having us all work off the same dev server over the network, and just push to it instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very late answer to a six-month old issue, and this might not be the actual problem. But I just found a repo that GitKraken couldn't handle, and narrowed down the problem. Turned out that in that repo's `.git/config` file, there were two sections with the following configuration:

```
[gitflow "branch"]
    master = master
    develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    support = support/
```

With those two sections in the repo's `.git/config` section, GitKraken wouldn't open the repo: it would just sit there with its "busy" spinner spinning, and spinning, and going nowhere. But if I removed those two `gitflow` sections from `.git/config`, GitKraken easily opened the repo, and the "busy" spinner was visible for just 2-3 seconds.

So if your repo uses git-flow, try removing those two config sections from a local copy of the repo and see if that allows Git Kraken to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Another even later, answer ...
I had a similar issue where GitKraken would give me a "could not find a compatible repository" error.  (I use gitflow with GitKraken, but that wasn't my problem, apparently.)

In the end I manually committed and pushed the changes I had made (through the CLI) and that got me past the problem, i.e. GitKraken could open the repo again.